# How do I fill a gap between wall tile and acrylic shower base

Tags: tile, gap

The bottom row of a newly installed tile wall has a gap with the shower base that is about 1/2 inch wide, too wide to caulk.  How can this be filled in a way that will not crack, will make a water tight seal between the shower base and wall and can be kept clean.  I am afraid I would damage or ruin the whole tile wall if I tried to remove the bottom row of subway tiles so I could replace them with custom cut tiles that would fit without a gap

Comment: What size tile are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the same tiles that you used, you could cut them to size (you may want to consider using a good cutter or wet saw). That way you can caulk the space in between the tile and the acrylic shower base. If you don't have any extra tiles or can't find any more of the same type, you could find a nice complementary looking small tile and install that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I'm afraid that my question must not have been clear.   What I am looking for is somw advise as to a substance to use as a filler with the characteristics of easy to clean, non-cracking and water resistant.   I tried calk but it required too thick an application to set up correctly and qickly cracked and discolored.   Looking for another option.  Thinset or  Hydrolic cement perhaps??

Comment: I am using 3 x 6 tiles and I also have the matching 6 x 6 tiles if I was to replace the bottom row of tiles with custom cuts that fit correctly.   My concern is that I will not be able to remove the bottom couse that is now there without damaging the entire shower wall.  The tiles are set on Hardiback with Mapei thinset and I don't know of a way to safely remove them or I would.   Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: @MarcS I would consider cutting your 3 x 6 tiles into 0.5" x 6" tiles (with space for the grout line between the existing tile). Then install them in the space in between and caulk in between the new tiles and the shower base

Answer (score 0):

Fill the space with grout and then clear caulk over that